# Quarkus/Kotlin: An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant with a java class

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

In a quarkus/kotlin app, I have a rest client that is very basic:

```
@Path("/my/api/v1")
@RestClient
interface MyApiClient { }
```

Problem is, when a request fails, it returns a response that fails to be mapped. So I want to add an exception mapper, in order to log the real error:

```
class MyExceptionMapper : ResponseExceptionMapper<java.lang.RuntimeException?> {
    override fun toThrowable(r: Response): java.lang.RuntimeException {
        Logger.getLogger(MyApiClient::class.java).error(r.status)
        return RuntimeException("failed")
    }
}
```

To do so, I should annoate my client with:

```
@RegisterProvider(MyExceptionMapper::class.java)
```

Doing so, I have a kotlin error:

An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant

I googled but could find solutions only for strings. In this case, kotlin expects the java class to be a compile time constant. How to get it?

Comment: Using the solution from @Михаил_Нафталь, did you get this ever to work? What did you do? My ResponseExceptionMapper doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Should work with simple:

```kotlin
@RegisterProvider(MyExceptionMapper::class)
```